# Divisor over a variety for discrepancy.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the context of defining discrepancy for a pair $(X,\Delta)$ Kollár-Mori in Birational Geometry of Algebraic Varieties say that for a birational morphism $f\colon Y\to X$ from a normal variety a divisor over $X$ is simply a prime divisor on $Y$. Then we use this terminology to define the discrepancy and total discrepancy. However in the book $a(E,X,\Delta)$ is defined only for a prime divisor of $X$ or an irreducible excpetional divisor on $Y$.

So is a divisor over $X$ a prime divisor on $Y$ ? And in this case how do we define $a(E,X,\Delta )$ ? Or is a divisor over $X$ an irreducible excpetional divisor on $Y$ ?

Comment: It should be the same definition right? Just $-\operatorname{coeff}_E(\Delta_Y)$ where $K_Y + \Delta_Y = f^*(K_X + \Delta).$ Why wouldn't this definition work?

Comment: @Daniel In Kollár-Mori's book I believe that $a(E,X\Delta)$ is defined only for $E$ an exceptional divisor.  I think your deifnition is more like Fujino's definition. So we would have $K_Y+f_*^{-1}\Delta =f^*(K_X+\Delta)+\sum_{E \text{ exceptional}}a(E,X,\Delta)E$. We can write $f_*^{-1}\Delta=\sum_{F}a(F,X,\Delta)F$ for some prime divisors and coefficients. What about the prime divisors which do not appear in $\{E\}$ or $\{F\}$ then ? Is their coefficient equal to 0 ? This would imply that the discrepancy is always $\leq 0$ no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My copy of Kollár-Mori has the equation $$K_Y \equiv f^*(K_X + \Delta) + \sum_{E_i \text{ arbitrary}} a(E_i, X, \Delta) E_i$$ under notation $2.26$ on page $51$. Since the expression $\sum_{E_i \text{ arbitrary}} a(E_i, X, \Delta) E_i$ is a divisor, all but finitely many coefficients are zero, so the total discrepancy of a pair $(X, \Delta)$ is indeed always $\leq 0$.

As you observed, if $a(E, X, \Delta) \neq 0$, then $E$ is either exceptional, or the birational transform of a component of $\Delta$.

A useful consequence of this is that if $\Delta \geq 0$ then the only divisors $E$ over $X$ with $a(E, X, \Delta) > 0$ are exceptional.